# jqGrid, setting bg color on column cells when  column header is clicked 

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jgGrid 3.8. I have an issue. I want to color the background of cells, when the column header is clicked. I mean, ascending or descending datas bg colors must be different color of other column's cells. How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle. The event [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) will be called after the sorted data will be loaded and after the data paging so it is a good place to change the background color of cells based on the current sort order:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    if (ids) {
        var sortName = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','sortname');
        var sortOrder = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','sortorder');
        for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
            grid.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], sortName, '', '',
                        {style:(sortOrder==='asc'?'background:aqua;':
                                                  'background:yellow;')});
        }
    }
}
```

A working example which do this you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomSortColor.htm).

**UPDATED**: Look at the [modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GradientBackground.htm) also. The results seems look more nice as in the previous demo:

[image]

It shows gradient effect in all browsers excepting opera. In opera it is the same as the previous demo. In another my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132880/in-cell-data-bars-in-jqgrid-possible-or-not/4133016#4133016) I play more with the color gradient effects.

Comment: @Kerberos: I made some experiments with gradient effect and remember about the example which I made for you before. Look at the modified demo. It could be interesting for you.