# Custom css design examples for jqGrid

Tags: css, jquery-ui, user-interface, jqgrid

Does anyone have some nice looking custom css design examples for jqGrid, except those resulting from using jQuery UI? 
Some screenshots would be nice. I searched on google but I can't find any visual examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you mean. First of all jqGrid gives you possibility to display TreeGrids, Subgrids, Grouping etc. Even the "standard" grid can contains . One use jQuery UI CSS. So the look of grid can hard depend on the jQuery UI CSS which you use. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4943722/315935) and example. One can use HTML *inside* any cell. So the grid can look like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4133016/315935) and it can contain *any* other controls (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4842450/315935))

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I want is to see some custom design examples, independent of jQuery UI.

Comment: I tried to describe you that I don't understand how you define "design examples". 99% of design of simple grid will be defined in jQuery UI CSS, because jqGrid use it and can't work without you includes some jQuery UI CSS. All other are the part of *specific* problem with the *content* of the grid.

Comment: I know that jqGrid uses jQuery UI but I want to see some customized examples of a simple jqGrid, except those jQuery UI themes. Of course, by modifying the css files.