# jqGrid - mini percentage-bars inside cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I don't know what to correctly call them - ratio-bars, percentage-bars?

As example, I can provide this:

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters.html

Look at the column `compelete %`.

How to do this in jqGrid?

Comment: you'll be wanting to add some code that you have attempted to achieve yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the code of SlickGrid demo you will see that it uses `formatter: Slick.Formatters.PercentCompleteBar` defined in [slick.formatters.js](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.formatters.js). The code of `PercentCompleteBarFormatter` is clear enough. If it's what you need you can rewrite the code as [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) of jqGrid.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133016/315935) provide close implementation of percentage-bars. Probably it's what you need. The answer is old enough. It can be that you need make some small modification to include support of new versions of web browsers.

Comment: @GillBates: You are welcome! The actualized version of the referenced demo will look about like [the following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NumberWithGradientColor2.htm).