# How to assign a unique CSS id to each cell in a jqGrid?

Tags: css, jqgrid

It seems jqGrid is not assigning any CSS ids to cells by default.

Any tips how to go about it?

I notice I can assign classes per column as [per the wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options&s%5B%5D=class), but I would like to add CSS ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why jqGrid schould assign an additional CSS class for every cell if jqGrid **not use the class**? If you need to add a CSS class to some jqGrid cells you can use [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method.

```
$("#list").jqGrid('setCell', id, colName, '', "someCssClass");
```

See modified demo for [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069471/jqgrid-setting-to-colums-cells-bg-color-when-clicked-columnheader/4070790#4070790) as an example.

Comment: Appreciated Oleg. I want to use it with iMacros that needs proper css iding for usage :) Your example will get me there I think.

Comment: @giorgio79: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You should explain all more exactly.